# How to send notification from Firebase to node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone explain me how to send push notifications **from** firebase to node.js server? I can easily achieve this on android, but can't find any examples on node.js.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Thanks, but I ment to send it not to a JS client, but a node.js backend. If that's also suitable, please help me understand how to use it :)

Comment: Curious as to why you'd want to do this. GCM / FCM is meant for notifying client applications. When should the Node server be notified from Firebase? If you're referring to Firebase Database, why cant the Node server just subscribe to changes in the database?

Comment: I'm making a reminder app, hence it needs to be pricise. I'm trying to achieve the following: I send a query to FCM and it makes a notification, which will be sent to my server to further call appropriate APIs. @AndrewBrooke

Comment: "I send a query to FCM". What do you mean by this? At what point should the server be notified of something?

Comment: To create a notification at a given time. Server should be notified when notification is set on (when a person should be notified). Maybe you could suggest other solutions for achieving this? @AndrewBrooke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135212/discussion-between-andrew-brooke-and-vaclovas-rekasius-jr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndrewBrooke , he suggested good node modules that could achieve similar effect (cron-like jobs, that can be initialised once needed): https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron , https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule , https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-crontab